# Python get indication is my text is mirror

Tags: python, hebrew

how can I check if my text is mirror

for example if my text is "שלום" or "םולש"
this happens with hebrew which is RTL

I am getting files that the text sometimes is mirror

I have to check if the text is mirror if it is to use    bidi.algoritm.get_display()  to extract the text

Comment: Trying to get a machine to compute things that even a human can't do is  not easy. Is "kanasak" mirrored or not? Or do you have any constraints you forgot to mention in the question?

Comment: ... Are none of the rest of you familiar at all with the Hebrew language? The question is **not** about text extraction and it is **not** about checking the order of characters and it is **not** about looking for palindromes. Hebrew text is supposed to be written right-to-left (RTL) as OP noted. Sometimes text is manually reversed in order to account for environments that don't know how to render RTL text. Sometimes it renders reversed because the text contains special text-direction-indicating characters that are being used incorrectly. **Many** things can go wrong here.

Comment: @DarkKnight no, there is no reason to expect code for a question like this, because it clearly is a how-to question, not a question about a problem in existing code. There **is** reason to expect more detail in the form of *exact input and output cases* - with test cases that can reliably reproduce the problem OP is encountering. Sometimes, typing it out into the question won't adequately exhibit the problem. I'm not completely sure that even copying and pasting it will work because there could be some Unicode normalization occuring at some point in the Markdown rendering.

Comment: OP: please read [mre] and try to figure out examples of the input that others can use for testing reliably. Text is hard and the BIDI algorithm is *especially* tricky. The best way to make sure that everyone knows the exact file contents for an example file, is to hex-dump the files (after editing them into a short example that still demonstrates the problem) and show the hex codes, along with the (known) encoding of the file (this will *usually* be UTF-8, but it's necessary to check).

Comment: What are your inputs even like? `.txt` files?

Comment: I am getting pdf file to s3 aws bucket and extract the text by pdfMiner somtimes the text is mirror and somtimes is not... so i have to get an indication and then to use or not with bidi.get_display